# Controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a directive on a controller. The directive will create a table of items returned from djangorestframework.

**controller.js:**

```
var expensesApp = angular.module('expensesApp', []);

expensesApp.controller('ShoppingListController', ['$scope', '$http', 
    function($scope, $http){

    $http(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/items/?format=json'
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.items = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });

}]);
```

**directive.js**

```
angular.module('expensesApp', [])
    .directive('shoppingList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/static/angular/partials/shopping-list.html',
            controller: 'ShoppingListController'
        };
    })
```

The partial being pulled in by the directive:

**shopping-list.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>SHOP</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>[[ item.id ]]</td>
            <td>[[ item.name ]]</td>
            <td>[[ item.shop ]]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the main html page where I define the app and the controller.

**items.html**

```
...
<div class="container" ng-app="expensesApp">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="ShoppingListController">
                <div shopping-list></div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
...
```

The headers of the table in the partial are being pulled into the page, but it's not executing the $http and fetching the items that should make up the content of the table. I get `ShoppingListController not a function, got undefined`

Everything works if I don't split the table out into a directive. All items are returned and I don't see the error in the console.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining module when you create a directive. It should be:

```
angular.module('expensesApp')
.directive('shoppingList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/static/angular/partials/shopping-list.html',
        controller: 'ShoppingListController'
    };
});
```

If you pass an array as the second argument to module method `angular.module('expensesApp', [])`, Angular creates a new module without `ShoppingListController` controller in it. You should use getter syntax `angular.module('expensesApp')` to retrieve previously created module.